# How to generate a function call in javascript with actual parameters

Tags: javascript

I am using this at the moment

```
return '<img src="../images/fam/bug.gif"/ onclick="showDetails(event,\''+
         IPatient+'\',\''+
         nom +'\',\'' + 
         prenom+'\',\''+
         mesure_decision+'\',\''+
         type_mesure+'\')">';
```

and I am sure there is a much more elegant way to write this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use some support library, such as JQuery... writing onclick handlers like you have on dynamic tags is not really elegant...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you don't need jQuery for [handling click events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), neither do you for [creating elements dynamically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).

Comment: Of course not, but in case one does not know how to do it without jquery then using jquery would help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in an array, then use `.join()`

```
var args = [IPatient,nom,prenom,mesure_decision,type_mesure];
return '<img src="../images/fam/bug.gif"/ onclick="showDetails(event,\''+args.join("','")+'\');">';
```

Though as mentioned by Antti Haapala, you should really be binding event handlers properly rather than using `on*=""` attributes

A quick possible integrated solution:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '../images/fam/bug.gif';
var args = [IPatient,nom,prenom,mesure_decision,type_mesure];
if(img.addEventListener) img.addEventListener('click',function(e) { showDetails.apply([e].concat(args)); });
if(img.attachEvent) img.attachEvent('onclick',function(e) { showDetails.apply([e].concat(args)); });
return img;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', '../images/fam/bug.gif');
img.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    showDetails(event, 'IPatient', 'nom', 'prenom', 'mesure_decision', 'type_mesure');
});
return img;
```

Comment: 'IPatient', 'nom', 'prenom', 'mesure_decision', 'type_mesure' are variable, not constant

Answer (score 1):

it's always better to create the event handlers vs inline as you have much more control over it.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.myInfo=[IPatient,nom,prenom,mesure_decision,type_mesure];
img.src='../images/fam/bug.gif';
img.addEventListener('click',showDetails,false);
return img;
```

inside the function showDetails

```
function showDetails(e){
 console.log(this.myInfo,e,e.target)
 var i=this.myInfo;
 console.log(i[0],i[1],i[2],'....');
 //if you want aslo more control here use {'IPa':IPatient,'nom':nom.....}
 // so that you can write i.IPa, i.nom.....
}
```

in this case you can use removeEventListener if you remove the image later 
but most of all it's easier to modify your existing code later.

```
function deleteImage(e){
 delete this.myInfo
 this.removeEventListener('click',showDetails,false)
 //.... 
}
```

everything in javacript is a object so you just can add parameters.
and in this case this is  very usefull.

ie

```
img[img.addEventListener?'addEventListener':'attachEvent']('click',showDetails);
img[img.removeEventListener?'removeEventListener':'detachEvent']('click',showDetails);

function showDetails(e){
 e=e||window.event;
 console.log(this.myInfo,e,e.target||e.srcElement);
}
```